# Proving that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{3408 k^2+1974 k-720}{128 k^6+480 k^5+680 k^4+450 k^3+137 k^2+15 k} = \pi$

Tags: sequences-and-series, polynomials, pi

I am trying to prove that $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{3408 k^2+1974 k-720}{128 k^6+480 k^5+680 k^4+450 k^3+137 k^2+15 k} = \pi$$

This is what I've tried to simplify the sum:

$$\frac{3408 k^2+1974 k-720}{128 k^6+480 k^5+680 k^4+450 k^3+137 k^2+15 k} = 0 \implies k = \frac{\sqrt{380881}-329}{1136}
$$

The minimal polynomial of the root is $568 k^2+329 k-120$.

Now, seeing as the numberator also has the form $xk^2+yk+z$, and $\frac{720}{120} = 6,\,\frac{1974}{329} = 6,\,\frac{3408}{568} = 6$; I tried to reduce the fraction by dividing by $6$, which yielded:
$$\frac{1}{6}\frac{3408 k^2+1974 k-720}{128 k^6+480 k^5+680 k^4+450 k^3+137 k^2+15 k} = \frac{568 k^2+329 k-120}{128 k^6+480 k^5+680 k^4+450 k^3+137 k^2+15 k}$$

which implies that $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{568 k^2+329 k-120}{128 k^6+480 k^5+680 k^4+450 k^3+137 k^2+15 k} = \frac{\pi}{6}$$

Where to go from here?

Comment: Your denominator factors into $k (k + 1) (2 k + 1) (4 k + 1) (4 k + 3) (4 k + 5)$.  Try partial fractions and see what the sum looks like.

Comment: @BarryCipra: I've tried that, and unfortunately, using the partial fraction ($\frac{119}{3 (k+1)}-\frac{190}{2 k+1}+\frac{667}{3 (4 k+1)}+\frac{126}{4 k+3}-\frac{95}{4 k+5}-\frac{8}{k}$) to calculate partial sums doesn't help me in proving this as I can't find a form for the partial sums.

Comment: Please tell us where did you find such a formula?

Comment: Use $\displaystyle{\large\sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1}{1 \over z + k} = \Psi\left(z + n\right) - \Psi\left(z\right)}$ in each term of your partial fraction...

Comment: @user37238: I found it by "accident" while solving another problem, not knowing why this is the case.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{3408 k^2+1974 k-720}{128 k^6+480 k^5+680 k^4+450 k^3+137 k^2+15 k}
$$
$$=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}
\left(
-\frac{192}{4k}+\frac{1334}{4k+1}-\frac{2280}{4k+2}+\frac{756}{4k+3}+\frac{952}{4k+4}-\frac{570}{4k+5}\right)
$$

$$
= 
-952 \color{blue}{\underbrace{
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left( \frac{1}{4k}-\frac{1}{4k+4} \right)}_{A}} 
+ 570 \color{darkgreen}{\underbrace{
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left( \frac{1}{4k+1}-\frac{1}{4k+5} \right)}_{B}}
+760 \color{red}{\underbrace{\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left( \frac{1}{4k}+\frac{1}{4k+1}-\frac{3}{4k+2}+\frac{1}{4k+3} \right)}_{C}}
+4 \color{darkviolet}{\underbrace{
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left( \frac{1}{4k+1}-\frac{1}{4k+3} \right)}_{D}}
$$
$$
=
-952\cdot \color{blue}{\frac{1}{4}} 
+570\cdot \color{darkgreen}{\frac{1}{5}}
+760\cdot \color{red}{\frac{1}{6}}
+4 \color{darkviolet}{\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{2}{3}\right)}=\Large{\pi}.
$$

---

Small explanation:

$$
\color{blue}{A=} \frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{8}-\frac{1}{12}+\frac{1}{12}-\frac{1}{16}+\frac{1}{16}-\ldots \color{blue}{=\frac{1}{4}}.
$$
$$
\color{darkgreen}{B=} \frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{9}+\frac{1}{9}-\frac{1}{13}+\frac{1}{13}-\frac{1}{17}+\frac{1}{17}-\ldots \color{darkgreen}{=\frac{1}{5}}.
$$

$$
\color{red}{C=}  
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} 
\left( -\frac{1}{4k}+\frac{1}{4k+1}-\frac{1}{4k+2}+\frac{1}{4k+3} \right) + 
 \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} 
\left( \frac{2}{4k}-\frac{2}{4k+2}\right) 
$$
$$
= 
\sum_{n=4}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n} + \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n} = 
\Bigl(\ln 2 - 1 +\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}\Bigr) - \Bigl(\ln 2-1\Bigr) \color{red}{=\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{3} = \frac{1}{6}}. 
$$

$$
\color{darkviolet}{D=} 
\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n}}{2n+1} = \frac{\pi}{4} - 1 + \frac{1}{3} \color{darkviolet}{=\frac{\pi}{4} - \frac{2}{3}}.
$$

Here we used [$\ln 2$ series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_logarithm_of_2) (for $C$) and [Leibniz formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_%CF%80) (for $D$).

---

Same way we can generate other similar series for $\large \pi$:

$$
0\cdot A + 0\cdot B + 8 \cdot C + 4 \cdot D = 
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} 
\frac
{80k^2+88k+12}
{k(2k+1)(4k+1)(4k+3)}
= \Large \pi.
$$
$$
-40\cdot A + 0\cdot B + 76 \cdot C + 4 \cdot D  
= 
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} 
\frac
{228k^2+225k+27}
{k(k+1)(2k+1)(4k+1)(4k+3)}
= \Large \pi.
$$

Exclusivity of your series is better asymptotic: ~ $\dfrac{1}{k^4}$.

Answer (score 7):

Note that for $a > 0$ and $b \ge 0$, 
$$\sum_{k=1}^N \dfrac{1}{ak+b} = \frac{\Psi(N+1+b/a) - \Psi(1+b/a)}{a}
= \frac{\ln(N) - \Psi(1+b/a) + O(1/N)}{a}$$
where $\Psi$ is the digamma function.  It may help to know 
$$\eqalign{\Psi \left( 1 \right) &=-\gamma\cr
\Psi \left( 5/4 \right) &=4-\gamma-3\,\ln  \left( 2 \right) -\pi/2 \cr
\Psi \left( 3/2 \right) &=2-\gamma-2\,\ln  \left( 2 \right)\cr 
\Psi \left( 7/4 \right) &=4/3-\gamma-3\,\ln  \left( 2 \right) +\pi/2 \cr
\Psi \left( 2 \right) &=1-\gamma\cr
\Psi \left( 9/4 \right) &={ {24}/{5}}-\gamma-3\,\ln  \left( 2
 \right) -\pi/2\cr}$$

Comment: Thanks, I'll edit the typo.