# A proof of a representation for $\sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{1}{ax+b}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, gamma-function

An answer to the [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/511914/proving-that-sum-k-1-infty-frac3408-k21974-k-720128-k6480-k5680?rq=1). A formula is mentioned $$\sum_{k=1}^N \dfrac{1}{ak+b} = \frac{\Psi(N+1+b/a) - \Psi(1+b/a)}{a}
= \frac{\ln(N) - \Psi(1+b/a) + O(1/N)}{a}$$
I want a proof for this.

Comment: Typos, otherwise: $\sum_{n=1}^N \dfrac{1}{ax+b}=\sum_{k=1}^N \dfrac{1}{ax+b}=\dfrac{N}{ax+b}$

Comment: @draks... What is Typos?

Comment: Have a look at the title...

Comment: "I want a proof for this". If you look at the definition of the [digamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function), you will see that this identity is just a reformulation of the definition (see paragraph "Recurrence formula and characterization").

Answer (score 1):

We have:
$$ \sum_{k\geq 1}\left(\frac{1}{k+c}-\frac{1}{k+d}\right) = \psi(d+1)-\psi(c+1) \tag{1}$$
together with:
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{N}\frac{1}{ak+b} = \frac{1}{a}\sum_{k=1}^{N}\frac{1}{k+\frac{b}{a}} = \frac{1}{a}\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\left(\frac{1}{k+\frac{b}{a}}-\frac{1}{k+\frac{b}{a}+N}\right)\tag{2}$$
and:
$$ \psi(m) = \log(m)-\frac{1}{2m}+O\left(\frac{1}{m^2}\right)\tag{3} $$
for any large $m$.