Infinite sum calculation by telescoping series
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{{n}^{4}+40{n}^3+225{n}^2 +248n+4}{{n}^{6}+19{n}^{5}+101{n}^{4}+103{n}^{3}+19{n}^{2}-5n+7}$$
This is the problem I want to evaluate.
Context
This is a problem that I found online related to an exam in India for high school students.
.
My approach
I know that we will have to make telescoping series. Tried factorizing the numerator. Failed. Tried long division but getting lengthy expressions which I do not think will help. I do not know any other approach. Any hints would help a lot.

Hint: Since you want to write is as $f(n+1) - f(n)$, and it's likely that $f(n) = g(n) / h(n)$ giving us $f(n+1) - f(n) = [g(n+1)h(n) - g(n)h(n+1)] / [ h(n)h(n+1)]$, so you should look to factorizing the denominator instead of the numerator. It can indeed be written in that form, and then you just have to determine $g(n)$. $\quad$ Equivalently, find the partial fraction form and force it into $f(n+1) - f(n)$.

@CalvinLin I do not think the denominator has any proper factors.

(Trivially but uselessly, it has 6 complex roots and can be factored as $ \prod ( n + \omega_i)$. Though we would ideally want it as $h(n)h(n+1)$) $\quad$ Can you substantiate your thoughts? How can we prove that it cannot be factorized? What did you try? What tools did you use? $\quad$ FWIW I said "it can indeed be written in that form". I had verified it before posting, so trust me that it can be factored accordingly. In fact, the partial fractions form immediately gives us $f(n+1) - f(n)$, though that requires factoring the denominator.

@CalvinLin I'm sorry, so in the partial fractions, do we use complex umbers or do I have to apply some other trick for factoring?

Oh, as an aside, it's not always true that the telescoping is $f(n+1) -f(n)$, as sometimes it's $f(n+k) - f(n)$. So, we want to check that the factorization is $h(n+k) h(n)$, and in this case $k = 1$ works.

No, the complex numbers approach is "trivial but useless" like I mentioned. $\quad$ (Assuming a nice solution exists) Show that there are no rational linear factors. Hence we want a factorization into cubics. (Why not quadratics?) After that, just brute force your way though via $( n^3 + an^2 + bn \pm 7)(n^3 + cn^2 + dn \pm 1)$.$\quad$ Because of the $h(n+k)h(n)$ factorization (see previous comment), we have $ a =  n \pm 3k$. With $k = 1$, this gives us $ { a, c } = { 8, 11 }$. Likewise, find a equation for $b, d$ to be of the form $h(n+1) h(n)$, so the factorization is less brute force

This has to be a joke, high school exam?

@whatamidoing It's not, really, it's considered one of the toughest in the world

@Someone sorry but what is considered the toughest? is this from a math contest/olympiad?

@whatamidoing JEE Advance + olympiads

@Someone, when i prepared for them, never saw such crazy summations(got a feeling there is a typo in the question which isn't allowing a straight forward "telescoping" split), anyways here's a reference - https://math.stackexchange.com/q/511914/1157207

Hints
As already said in comments, the denominator is
$$\left(n^3+8 n^2-3 n+1\right)\left(n^3+11 n^2+16 n+7\right)$$ So, partial fraction decomposition first.
Now, if you write
$$n^3+8 n^2-3 n+1=(n-a_1)\,(n-(b_1+i c_1))\,(n-(b_1-ic_1))$$
$$n^3+11 n^2+16 n+7=(n-a_2)\,(n-(b_2+i c_2))\,(n-(b_2-ic_2))$$ you should notice that
$$a_2=a_1-1 \qquad\qquad b_2=b_1-1 \qquad\qquad c_1=c_2$$
Concerning the quadratics resulting from the partial fraction decomposition, there are similar things (I let you the work).
Using all of the above, by a simple change of variables, you should be able to find the telescoping sum which leads to a simple result.
Edit
Since @abomasnow provided the answer, I shall finish mine
$$A_n=\frac{n^4+40 n^3+225 n^2+248
   n+4}{n^6+19 n^5+101 n^4+103 n^3+19
   n^2-5 n+7}$$
$$A_n=\frac{n^4+40 n^3+225 n^2+248
   n+4}{\left(n^3+8 n^2-3 n+1\right)
   \left(n^3+11 n^2+16 n+7\right)}$$
$$A_n=\frac{n^2+19 n+4}{n^3+8 n^2-3 n+1}-\frac{n^2+21 n+24}{n^3+11 n^2+16 n+7}$$
Let $(n_1,n_2)$ be the roots of $n^2+19 n+4=0$ and
$(m_1,m_2,m_3)$ be the roots $n^3+8 n^2-3 n+1=0$. We have
$$A_n=\frac{(n-n_1)(n-n_2) } {(n-m_1)(n-m_2)-(n-m_3)}-$$ $$\frac{(n+1-n_1)(n+1-n_2) } {(n+1-m_1)(n+1-m_2)-(n+1-m_3)}$$ which shows the telecoping process.
So, the infinite sum write
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty A_n=\frac {(1-n_1)(1-n_2) } {(1-m_1)(1-m_2)(1-m_3)  }$$ that is to say
$$\frac {1-(n_1+n_2)+n_1n_2} { 1-(m_1+m_2+m_3)+(m_1m_2+m_1m_3+m_2m_3)-m_1m_2m_3}$$ which is easy to compute using Vieta's formulae.
